# getting build errors while using aws-iot-device-sdk in reactjs application

Tags: reactjs, aws-iot

I am trying to use `aws-iot-device-sdk` js sdk in our reactjs application. I am getting below errors..

`ERROR in ./~/aws-iot-device-sdk/common/lib/tls-reader.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/xxxxx/react/aws-iot/node_modules/aws-iot-device-sdk/common/lib
 @ ./~/aws-iot-device-sdk/common/lib/tls-reader.js 17:16-29`

`ERROR in ./~/aws-iot-device-sdk/device/lib/tls.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'tls' in /Users/xxxx/react/aws-iot/node_modules/aws-iot-device-sdk/device/lib
 @ ./~/aws-iot-device-sdk/device/lib/tls.js 17:10-24`

How to get rid of these errors?

Comment: https://github.com/josephsavona/valuable/issues/9

Comment: @Shota I've already tried that but no luck. I am getting error like Uncaught TypeError: filesys.existsSync is not a function

Comment: @Shota Sorry, I am getting below error
`ERROR in ./~/aws-iot-device-sdk/~/mqtt/mqtt.js
Module parse failed: /Users/xxxx/react/aws-iot/node_modules/aws-iot-device-sdk/node_modules/mqtt/mqtt.js Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)`

Comment: The error message says you need appropriate loader, which means you lack some webpack loader

Comment: Yeah, I understood it but we dont generally babelify node_modules, right? I think if we babelify node_modules/aws-iot-device-sdk/, it will resolve but are we supposed to do this

Comment: That is true, did you try to removing the nodes_module folder and re-installing deps?

Comment: Yeah, that is the first thing I generally do when I got these type of issues

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question. However, with ReactJS applications, generally with browser-based frontend applications, you should use the [AWS JavaScript SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/getting-started-browser.html). The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sdks.html) for the `aws-iot-device-sdk` states

> These SDKs are for use on your IoT device. If you're developing an IoT app for use on a mobile device, see the [AWS Mobile SDKs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sdks.html#iot-mobile-sdks). If you're developing an IoT app or server-side program, see the [AWS SDKs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-connect-service.html#iot-service-sdks).